# Problems with asset precompile after updating to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I am updating a Rails application from 3.2.12 to 4.0.0.beta1. I had a few minor issues but I could get the app running and all tests passing again. The problem is when I try to precompile all the assets for deployment, I get the following error:

```
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
No such file to load -- bootstrap_flash_helper
/vagrant/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0.beta1'

gem 'pg'
gem 'github_api'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'simple_form', github: 'plataformatec/simple_form'
gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise', branch: 'rails4'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-github'
gem 'rails-backbone', '~> 0.9.10'
gem 'inherited_resources'
gem 'app_configuration'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'foreman'
gem 'coveralls', require: false

group :assets do
  gem 'sprockets-rails',  github: 'rails/sprockets-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails',     github: 'rails/coffee-rails'
  gem 'therubyracer',     platforms: :ruby
  gem 'less-rails',       github: 'metaskills/less-rails'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'meta_request'
end

group :test, :development do
  # Debugging
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'debugger-pry'
  gem 'pry-nav'
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'

  # Testing
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker'
  # gem 'cucumber-rails', '~>1.3.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'
end
```

The project is open source (work in progress), here is the github repository https://github.com/wolox/mgmt

Any idea about what I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The :assets group is not loaded in the **production** environment by default, you can change this in your config/application.rb (https://github.com/Wolox/mgmt/blob/master/config/application.rb#L7 in your repo)

The advised practice is to compile your assets in development and then push the /public/assets directory to production once you're satisfied nothing breaks.

Use this line instead, and you should be fine:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, then I found that ***group :assets*** doesn't exist anymore. After clonning your repo, I deleted the ***group :assets*** from your Gemfile, then your assets precompiled ok!